# How to manage a field collection in a table?

Tags: entities

I have a field collection called *My links*.

*My links* contains these fields:

1. Organization Name (*Text Field*)
2. Description (*Long text with summary*)
3. Link Url (*Link Field*)

This is a pain to manage because I need to scroll down really often since I have at least 45 links in there.

Is there a way to manage these link in a table format?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with the [Field Collection Table](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_table) module:

> Provides a table formatter for the Field Collection module.

Comment: +vote up,I use it before and worked correctly.as  always good suggestion Master Clive ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a frontend solution, Clive answer is probably the good one. If you search for a backend solution (node edit form), [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module is probably the solution.

Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.

Comment: Ah yes, I think that's more likely what the OP is looking for after re-reading

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the [Field Collection Fieldset](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection_fieldset) module.  This wraps each field collection "row" in a collapsed fieldset.

You can set one of your fields to be the label of the fieldset (e.g. Orgainisation Name) and if you do that then your admin screen would appear as a vertical list of expandable titles and when you click on any of them it opens up to reveal the 3 fields for that particular row.